# How to Find the location of a value in a multi row/column Excel spreadsheet table?

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula, lookup

How do I find either the cell address or preferably the row and column of the value 119, or any other number in the table below?

The table does not contain row or column titles, only the numbers as shown.

I am looking for a worksheet solution (formula) and not a VBA solution.

[image: Number Matrix]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## An Array Formula

This is an **array formula** and it has to be entered with **control shift enter** i.e. hold control shift and then press enter.

```
=MAX(IF(A1:J34=119,ROW(A1:J34)-ROW(A1)+1))
```

**Remarks:**

The value is searched by column i.e. `A1, A2, ... B1, B2 ...` i.e. if  you had another `119` in cell `D1` the result would still be **2**, and if       you had a `119` in cell `c1` then the result would be
**1**.

For a column version just replace ROW with COLUMN:

```
=MAX(IF(A1:J34=119,COLUMN(A1:J34)-COLUMN(A1)+1))
```

Comment: Thank you VBasic2008. This is the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, clunky and you can expand it, but it does work:

[image]

Row is separate to column but you could put them together in one cell, does depend on how you want to use the results, but you did not specify that so I have done this...

You could use a choose() function or a lookup table with vlookup() to change the column result to a letter...

Comment: I was going to post something similar... I thought you might as well return the row and column at the same time, e.g.:
`=IFERROR("A_"&MATCH(E2,A1:A3,0),IFERROR("B_"&MATCH(E2,B1:B3,0),IFERROR("C_"&MATCH(E2,C1:C3,0),"XX")))`

Comment: @David you should still post yours as it is shorter than mine and just as valid...

Comment: An interesting solution. However, could be too involved for a large table. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Sammy I enjoyed making it work, but there are more elegant solutions which is fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=MOD((K1-50),34)+1&" | "&1+(INT((K1-50)/34))
```

where `K1` is your selected value.

Returns `R | C`. (Data in A1:J34 is not required.)

Comment: This works and produces the same results as my, much longer, effort above and demonstrates superb knowledge, plus 1 from me...

Comment: pnuts: Very cool method indeed. Sorry if my example portrayed a numerical only type problem. I actually need a solution that works for any type of data, not just numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a general purpose answer based on VBasic2008's answer.

I modified the formulas to utilize defined names so that the cell references do not have to be hard coded in the formulas. This way both the data table and row / column formulas can be relocated to anywhere on the spreadsheet. It works for both numerical AND text based data.

I also included the =ADDRESS() function to return the absolute reference of the look up value.

For illustration purposes, a step by step example for Data Set 1 is shown replacing the hard coded cell references with defined names.

The Data Set 2 section is the simplified version just using one defined for each the row and column look up value.

You can download an example spreadsheet here: [Look_Up_a_Value_in_a_Table.xls](http://sam308.com/download/Look_Up_a_Value_in_a_Table.xls)

Thanks to all of you: Solar Mike, VBasic2008, and pnuts

Click on the image to enlarge.

[image]